# How to embed an Android app's data together with the app into a new apk file?

Tags: apk

I found this Windows program to embed an Android app's data into a new apk together with the app.
https://github.com/And42/SaveToGame/releases

But it seems it uses old smali, baksmali, apktool files.
I tried with new files but it didn't make a difference.

To change the language to English, just change the first menu option and select the language as English.

If someone can test the program and see if they can get it to work, please let me know.

I tried it with a couple of apps like Kodi, but after installing the modded apk, it seems just like a regular install and doesn't restore any data or user settings. Some other apps also can't be repacked probably because of old jar files, apktool it still uses.

To use it
1) You make a backup of your app with Titanium Backup
2) Load the apk with the first button in the program
3) Load the tar.gz app data backup made with Titanium backup with the second button in the program
4) The third button creates the modded app that includes the app data.

This would be great to use to install an app with it's data on non rooted Android devices.

Comment: When installing an app with data the better way is to use `adb backup` and `adb restore`. Modifying the APK is IMHO not a good idea.